# What do I need to change about my code to fix this error message?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

Every time I try to run my code I seem to get this error message and I cannot seem to fix it. Does anyone know what it's trying to tell me to change?

```
trials = 10000
num_different = 0
for i in np.arange(trials):
    words = np.random.choice(p_and_p_words, 2)
    if len(words.item(0)) != len(words.item(1)) != len(words.item(2)) != len(words.item(0)):
        num_different = num_different + 1
num_different = num_different / trials
num_different
```

```
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Comment: The error message says that you're trying to get the third item but there are only two. On the line before, you choose two random words, so that matches...

Comment: It seems to me `words` has only 2 elements, so `words.item(2)` fails. BTW, I'm not into python, but does `a != b != c != d` work? Don't you need separate `and` blocks? What if `a != b`, `b != c` but `a == c`?

Comment: It only has 2 elements because that's how many you ask for in the `np.random.choice` call